# email alert when user id or profile id chanages i wriiten these validation rule on user object

Tags: validation-rule

email alert when user id or profile id chanages i wriiten these validation rule on user object

```
AND (ISCHANGED(profileid ))||( ISCHANGED(OwnerId))
```

Comment: You can't send email alerts from a validation rule.

Comment: you need WF for this.

Answer (score 0):

For sending Email alert simple way is Workflow rule-
The ownerId is not valid field here Try This In Formula:-
AND(OR(ISCHANGED(profileid )),( ISCHANGED(Id)))